# MacBook Pro Retina cannot install Intel HAXM via Ruboto

Tags: android, ruby, macos, ruboto, haxm

I have a brand new MacBook Pro Retina 15" with the dedicated GPU.  I'm trying to install Ruboto, which has a nice setup to include the Android SDK, Java, etc.  But it fails on installing Intel HAXM with the following error:

> Error - Your computer does not meet the minimum requirements for this software. Intel(R) HAXM cannot be installed on this computer. Please refer to the Intel(R) HAXM documentation for more information.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes. What does the Intel documentation tell you about the requirements, and how do those differ from what you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem caused by using a case-sensitive file system.  The HAXM installation was dependent on /usr/bin/TRUE (and /usr/bin/FALSE), which in my case is not the same as /usr/bin/true (and /usr/bin/false).

Easily fixed by:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/true /usr/bin/TRUE
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/false /usr/bin/FALSE
```

Comment: not possible on macOS Siera `ln: /usr/bin/TRUE: Operation not permitted`